# Flutter - Display badge number on app icon when push notification arrives

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, badge, payload

I'm using [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) plugin in my Flutter app. For iOS, we have the option "**badge**" in the notification payload, the number will be displayed on the app icon when a notification comes to device (even if the app is terminated). Do we have any option to add "badge" through notification payload like iOS for Android?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [flutter_app_badge](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger) package to do your task done. Also here is an [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger/example) which will help you understand the implementation of package

Comment: I've tried the plugin but it requires opening the app to update the badge number. I want to show the badge number even when the app is terminated.

Comment: This example does not help so much actually.

Comment: You can use firebase background functions to update the badge on background when app is not open